# Django:What to use modelform,formset,model formset for the following scenario?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have this model:

```
class option(models.Model):
    warval = models.ForeignKey(war)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And I have few modelforms like:

```
class text_option(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = option
        exclude = ('url','warval','user')

class url_option(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = option
        exclude = ('text','warval','user')
    def clean_url(self):
            #processing...
```

I want my users to create as many options as they want.So the my option is using "formset".
But how can I instantiate all the forms in formset with the "war" instance("war" is a model).And also how to provide all the functionality of the above given modelforms in my formset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id of `war` instance either explicitly through url something like `http://myserver/add_options/1` where `1` is id of `war` and you use it in your view to update foreignkey field of options appropriately.

Another options is passing id as implicit/hidden input field in your form and using that id to identify `war` instance in the view.

On the side lines, may be you can make use of inheritance to simplify your model definition.
like:

```
class base_option(models.Model):
    warval = models.ForeignKey(war)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class text_option(base_option):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

class url_option(base_option):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
```